# Matthews correlation raising divide-by-zero error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, classification, text-classification

I am classifying some samples (number of classes: 117) with a trained model that outputs a matrix with shape `n_samples x n_classes`. Each row is the output of a sample, and each column is the output given by a neuron in the output layer of my model. Something like that:

```py
[[0.3, -0.47, 0.1], #sample 1
 [0.124, 0.442, -0.111], #sample 2
  ... # and so on
]
```

The final prediction is then calculated:

```py
pred_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1).flatten()
```

and then i calculate matthews correlation using `sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef`:

```py
matthews = mattews_corrcoef(true_labels, pred_labels)
```

This is raising a warning:

`invalid value encountered in double_scalars`

Doing some research in SO, this is mainly caused by a division-by-zero operation. Then i set `np.seterr('raise)` to debug where is this operation, and then i get to this line:

`--> 900 mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)`

It makes me believe that the denominator of this operation is 0 for some reason.  I double checked prediction and training phases, but there are no errors found.

Comment: Well, having some covariances = 0 is possible and not an error, the error appears when you divide by it, right?

Comment: Yes, but i have no control over cases like that. I mean, i just got the predictions and applied to the formula

Comment: Then this is a problem of how to use that formula, not of programming, perhaps

Comment: I don't know why, but this error is raised when i process MCC in prediction batches. If i concatenate all the batches and then apply MCC, i get no errors.

Comment: That's not surprising, correlations can be zero on a small batch, and non-zero on a larger dataset.

Comment: Thank you for that information. It makes total sense now :D.